Why gradient of dot product results in cross product?
On wiki page Vector_calculus_identities
It first says about the first derivative associative properties
$(\mathbf {A} \cdot \nabla )\mathbf {B} =\mathbf {A} \cdot (\nabla \mathbf {B} )$
Then in the identities it shows
$\nabla (\mathbf {A} \cdot \mathbf {B} )\ =\ (\mathbf {A} \cdot \nabla )\mathbf {B} +(\mathbf {B} \cdot \nabla )\mathbf {A} +\mathbf {A} {\times }(\nabla {\times }\mathbf {B} )+\mathbf {B} {\times }(\nabla {\times }\mathbf {A} )\ =\ \mathbf {A} \cdot \mathbf {J} _{\mathbf {B} }+\mathbf {B} \cdot \mathbf {J} _{\mathbf {A} }\ =\ (\nabla \mathbf {B} )\cdot \mathbf {A} +(\nabla \mathbf {A} )\cdot \mathbf {B}$
$\frac{1}{2}\nabla \left(\mathbf {A} \cdot \mathbf {A} \right)\ =\ \mathbf {A} \cdot \mathbf {J} _{\mathbf {A} } = (\nabla \mathbf {A} )\cdot \mathbf {A} = (\mathbf {A} {\cdot }\nabla )\mathbf {A} +\mathbf {A} {\times }(\nabla {\times }\mathbf {A} )\ = A\nabla A$
I am wondering where does the cross products come out, because the first equation will show the cross product part of the last two equations are zero. Does the last two contradict with the first equation?
Edited:
To make my question clearer, for example for the second equation going back to front
$ (\nabla \mathbf {B} )\cdot \mathbf {A} +(\nabla \mathbf {A} )\cdot \mathbf {B} = \mathbf {A} \cdot (\nabla \mathbf {B} ) + \mathbf {B} \cdot (\nabla \mathbf {A} ) = (\mathbf {A} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf {B}  + (\mathbf {B} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf {A} 
\stackrel{?}{=} (\mathbf {A} \cdot \nabla )\mathbf {B} +(\mathbf {B} \cdot \nabla )\mathbf {A} +\mathbf {A} {\times }(\nabla {\times }\mathbf {B} )+\mathbf {B} {\times }(\nabla {\times }\mathbf {A} )$

How do you see a contradiction? I don't see that they're related at all.

Note that in the first identity the gradient operator is acting on a single vector on both sides of the equality while in the second it's acting on the product of two vectors on the left-hand side.

You should interpret the first "property" as a definition of the symbol $(\mathbf A\cdot\nabla)$. The formula for $\nabla(\mathbf A\cdot\mathbf B)$ is just a product rule, made more complicated by the need to understand what $\nabla\mathbf A$ means in lieu of the gradient of a scalar function.
